# Free/Inexpensive IP blacklists

Tags: blacklist

What are some free or inexpensive places where I can grab blacklists automatically? I do not want to have to query for each individual IP. The firewall, PF, requires you to have the IPs or ranges in a file line by line.

Any type of blacklist applies -- but I am more worried about malicious content, such as botnets, compromised hosts, and phishing IPs.

I have tried to research this through Google, but a lot of resources are for how to remove yourself from a blacklist, and many providers are on a query basis only. I understand that most providers do not want to give away their entire database of IPs, but maybe there is a free list established by a consortium that I do not know of.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "where can I find product/service that does X?" are off-topic as the list of potential answers could go on forever.

Answer (score 0):

These two repositories have lists of their sources inside of their readmes:

https://github.com/maravento/blackip

https://github.com/mitchellkrogza/Ultimate.Hosts.Blacklist

Please note the first project is no longer maintained. The 2nd project only seems to update monthly.